# Making action when element appear on screen with jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, screen, element, show

how do I check during a scroll when an element "# my_div" appears on the screen with jquery??
and if it appears to do certain actions

Comment: [check this out](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport). It's a plugin that allows for new psuedo selectors, one of them being, `:in-viewport`, which is precisely what you want.

Comment: thank you, there is something easier, lighter?

Comment: @MarcelloViolini its just one line code $("#my_div")[0].offsetTop < (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is what you can use it will give true and false

```
$('#my_div').offset().top < ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop()) &&
($('#my_div').offset().top + $('#my_div').outerHeight()) > $(window).scrollTop()
```

first condition will check that the div is not completely below the viewport and second will check that it is not completely above the viewport

Comment: I'm just curious...why are you unwraping a jQuery object to use native JS on when you could just use native JS in the first place, or just use jQuery? If I were your average user, and I saw this code and it worked, i would continually mess my stuff up trying to do `[0]` and run jQuery methods after. Just saying...continuity (ps - still upvoted)

Comment: updated the condition and make it completely jQuery so that there will be no confusion